# Import only new rows into existing table using phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I have a WordPress website. I made a staging copy of the site so we can make our changes there. Now we are done with the changes and want to upload the new files and database of the staging site to Live. The catch is, we only want to import new/mutated rows from the .sql file of the staging site and retain existing rows on the Live site. Our wp_posts table on Live contains many existing order so we don't want that entire table to be overwritten if you know what I mean.

What's the best way to get this done with phpMyAdmin? We also don't mind doing this using mysql commands. Please explain.

Comment: Will you also update rows on the live website which got changed in the staging website?

Comment: yes, all the changed and new rows need to be updated/added

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
mysqldump --no-create-info --insert-ignore --quick --where="id between from and to" <db> <table> > table.sql
```

NB: add `--set-gtid-purged=OFF`: if GTID is enabled and don't want to capture.

`--no-create-info`: to ignore the schema to be run again.
`--insert-ignore`: add `insert ignore` statement instead of `insert`, if the id already exists on prod ignore that.
`--where`: to specify what range of staging you want to restore back on prod

EDIT:

`--replace`: replace `--insert-ignore` with `--replace` if you want duplicate rows to be replaced not ignored

Comment: This will not update existing rows whose data got changed

Comment: add --replace if you want existing ids to be changed as well.

Answer (score 0):

In the `sql` file you're importing through `PHPMyAdmin`, change all `INSERT` statements to `REPLACE`

```
REPLACE INTO `table_name` (`id`, `column_name`) VALUES (1, 'some_value')
```

[The manual for REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html) states that:

> REPLACE works exactly like INSERT, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted

i.e. the old row is replaced with the new one.

Note that for tables with no `UNIQUE` index or `PRIMARY KEY`, this won't work. However, given this is a Wordpress site, I think there'll hardly be any such table.

Comment: but this will replace one record at a time or what?

Comment: It will simply add new records and update existing ones (by existing, I mean records with the same primary key - which all wordpress default tables have - or unique index).